# Generate csv file from form data on fly then email to address

Tags: php, email, forms

I have a form that users are able to fill in and want to be able to generate an Excel file and populate it with the data from the form. I then want it to email me the file with the completed data. How can this be done?

This is currently generating the email:

```
    $body = "You have a new member account application from the website, please see the details below:

\n
Membership Type: $group1_field\n\n

Contact Details\n
Organisation: $member_organ_field\n
Address: $member_address_field\n
Postcode: $member_post_field\n
Tel: $member_tel_field\n
Fax: $member_fax_field\n
Email address: $member_email_field\n
Website: $member_website_field\n\n
Contacts \n
Member 1 \n
Name: $member1_name1_field\n
Position: $member1_position1_field\n
Direct Email: $member1_email1_field\n
Direct Tel: $member1_tel1_field\n\n
Member 2 \n
Name: $member1_name2_field\n
Position: $member1_position2_field\n
Direct Email: $member1_email2_field\n\n
Member 3 \n
Name: $member1_name3_field\n
Position: $member1_position3_field\n
Direct Email: $member1_email3_field\n\n
Type Of Organisation: ".$checkbox1results."\n
Type Of Activity: ".$checkbox2results."$member3_other_field\n\n
Summary Description \n
$member_summary_field \n\n
Company Information \n
Total no. of employees (Welsh site): $member4_total_field\n
Turnover (from Welsh site): $member4_turnover_field\n
Date of company formation: $member4__formation\n
Do you export aborad? Where? $member4_export_field\n\n
Member consent: ".$checkbox3results."\n\n
Completed by: $member4_com_field\n
Company position: $member4_com_pos_field\n
Invoice required: $CheckboxGroup4_field\n\n

Please follow up this request asap.\n\n
";

mail($to, $subject, $body);

echo "Thank you for your account application, we will contact you shortly.";

} ?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way would be can create a csv, which is readable by Excel.

It's essentially a comma seperated list of values. Each line representing a row.
The first line can optionally be the column headings, eg:

```
$string = '"Organisation","Address","Postcode"' . PHP_EOL;
$string .= "\"$member_organ_field\",\"$member_address_field\",\"$member_post_field\"" . PHP_EOL;

file_put_contents('myfile.csv', $string); // write file
```

Be sure to quote field names and values as a stray unquoted , (comma) would mess up your columns.

Other wise there is an [PEAR library](http://pear.php.net) for write excel files.

You can them email the file as an attachment using the [built-in mail function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php), [see example here](http://www.geekology.co.za/blog/2009/06/sending-emails-with-attachments-using-php-mail-function/)

Or using [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org), [see example here](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/message-attachments)

**UPDATE**

This is the general gist of what you need, the code may not be perfect to please read over it and don't copy and paste.

```
<?php

$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));

$csvString = "..."; // your entire csv as a string
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($csvString));

$to = "to@me.com";
$from = "from@you.com";
$subject = "my subject";
$body = "... what ever you want to appear in the body";

$headers = "From: $from\r\nReply-To: $from";
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";

$output = "
--PHP-mixed-$random_hash;
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary='PHP-alt-$random_hash'
--PHP-alt-$random_hash
Content-Type: text/plain; charset='iso-8859-1'
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
 
$body
 
--PHP-mixed-$random_hash
Content-Type: text/csv; name=mycsv.csv
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment
 
$attachment
--PHP-mixed-$random_hash--";

mail($to, $subject, $output, $headers);

echo "Thank you for your account application, we will contact you shortly.";

?>
```

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I want, how can this then be emailed to an address?

Comment: Using whatever email library you're using, simply add the file as an attachment after you write it to the hard drive. You can then delete when you're done sending the email.

Comment: Attachments can be a bit tricky with the built-in `mail` function. But probably possible, just google it. Although I would recomment PEAR Mail library or better yet Swift Mailer, see docs here (http://swiftmailer.org/docs/message-attachments)

Comment: So with this, the code you gave plus the geekology link will mail the completed form data in a csv format to an address? I'll give it a test now.

Comment: Not only is it not attaching the file but it's not outputting anything in the email. Is it trying to attach a file from my computer? I want it to generate the csv file on the fly then attach it and email it.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show a basic code example. Update the variables with your data and it should be a good starting point. This version attaches the file directly to the email without writing to the hard disk. To be honest, if you can't manage the headers required to send the attachment you really are best suing Swift Mailer. It requires almost no configuration and attachments couldn't be easier.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. Create a CSV file from the data above
2. Create an Excel spreadsheet from the data above

By default, windows will associate CSV files with Excel (if it's installed) so most people will open a CSV in Excel (if they have it installed).

For each case, read here:

1. http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/10131-working-with-excel-files-comma-delimited-or-csv/
2. http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

It's also worth noting that if you're generating a .xls file then your PHP will need to run on windows with a copy of Excel installed (I wouldn't advise this, and if you want to go with the Excel option then you might want to consider creating .xlsx files with the PHPExcel tool I linked you to, this does not require an installed copy of Excel and so it can be deployed on Linux)

EDIT: To email the files as attachments you can user PHPMailer (an example of how easy this is can be found [here](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=exampleamail), and you can download the class [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/PHPMailer%20v5.1/))

Comment: PHPExcel can also create BIFF8 .xls files as well as the newer Office Open Spreadsheet .xlsx files.

Comment: yeah, sorry... what I meant was that it's better to use the xlsx file extensions because you don't have to rely on COM objects to interact with Excel

Comment: The csv option seems like what I want, it seems like it saves the data as a csv file and saves it to the server. How could I get that file to be emailed to a certain address?

Comment: This sitepoint article explains how you can send email's with attachments: http://articles.sitepoint.com/print/advanced-email-php (just scroll down to the File Attachments section), but you might be better off using a helper class such as PHP Mailer: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=exampleamail

Comment: Sorry but I'm not too good at all this. Everyone's given me answers, which is great but assumed that I know a lot about the subject, I really need some to hold my hand through it all and what steps to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Pear could be useful here. I found: [Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer](http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/redirected). Basic documentation and usage for it is [here](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.intro.php).